# Swift: How to check whether dates are consecutive with custom predicate

Tags: arrays, swift, date, calendar

I am trying to write a function that check if the dates in an array (so type Date) are consecutive while excluding certain days of the week (which could be any, e.g. [1,4,6] or [] or [1,2,3,4,5]). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45941200/how-to-check-consecutive-weekdays-in-an-array#45950144) has a predicate that excludes weekends, but I haven't managed to modify this approach to take an array of .weekday

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried?

Comment: Hey @JoakimDanielson I haven't managed to write much code, I'm trying to wrap my head around what a solution should look like. Right now I'm trying to get the .weekday of today, which is where this function will always start from, then use that as an index to iterate through an array of Bools (that would represent the days of the week to filter for). So for [1,4,6] the array would be (Starting with Sunday) [true, false, false, false true, false, true]. What I'm struggling to figure out with this approach is how to search both backwards and forwards for the next bool that's true.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't share more code and for how vague the question is, but I'm finding it hard enough to understand it myself. This would be used for calculating a streak, and the only part I really need to figure out how to find is determining what was the next day backwards of forwards from Today that is enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a basic solution to build on, it converts the dates to an array of weekdays ([Int]) and then uses a for loop to validate the array.

```
let secondsPerDay = 24.0 * 60.0 * 60.0
var dates = [Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: -2.0 * secondsPerDay),
             Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: -1.0 * secondsPerDay),
             Date(),
             Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 2 * secondsPerDay),
             Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 3 * secondsPerDay),]

let calendar = Calendar.current
let excluded = [5, 6]

var weekdays = dates.map {calendar.component(.weekday, from: $0)}
var prev = weekdays.first!  //Change to a guard statement or similar
var isConsecutive = true

for index in 1..<weekdays.count {
    let weekday = weekdays[index]
    let previousWeekday = prev > weekday ? prev - 7 : prev

    if previousWeekday + 1 == weekday || excluded.contains(previousWeekday + 1) {
        prev = weekday
        continue
    }

    isConsecutive = false
    break
}

print("Date array is \(isConsecutive ? "" : "not ")consecutive" )
```